# Count rows of each csv file in a folder

Tags: python

how can I count the rows of each csv file in a folder ?

```
with open('filename.csv', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as csvfile:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

row_count=sum(1 for row in readCSV)
print(row_count)
for row in readCSV:
   print(row[1])
```

I tried this for one file but i want to do this for each file and there are many..

```
import os
a ="foldername"
os.listdir(a)
```

And I tried this but I don't know how it goes on..
I'm really new at python..

Thanks a lot.

Comment: if only to count the rows you don't need csv library. just open the file with readlines.

Comment: You don't need csvreader, open the file using `with` and do `len( your_file.readlines() )`, minus 1 for the header

Comment: your_file its my filename, right? Can I use something like a slope to set the filenames automatically ? I have no idea..

Comment: @Torb you can access all the files using `os.listdir(path)` as I suggested in my answer below, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to validate the CSV content or deal with edge cases (discarding some varying number of rows as headers, etc), then you do not need to read the CSV at all. `len(open(file).readlines())` will count the lines in each file for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the files are placed in a folder:

```
import os
path = '/some/path/to/file'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="latin-1") as fileObj:
        # -1 to exclude the header
        print("Rows Counted {} in the csv {}:".format(len(fileObj.readlines()) - 1, filename))
```

**OUTPUT** (tested):

```
Rows Counted 198 in the csv celebList.xlsx:
Rows Counted 148 in the csv cel_lis.xls:
```

Comment: @ChristophBurschka Indeed, fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This code should do

```
import os
import glob

path = "/home/.."
os.chdir(path)
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format("csv"))]

for i in result:
   with open(i, 'r', encoding="latin-1") as csvfile:
    print(i, ": ", str(len(csvfile.readlines()) - 1))
```

Comment: I would not recommend using `os.chdir(path)` when you can pass in the complete path using `os.path.join`